# style first child of <UL> (not sub <ul> without adding ID's or Classes)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists, parent-child

**Thank you for your answers. I am waiting on a Cache plugin to be removed before I can test and confirm everythign is working correctly.

I have a unordered list that contains some sublist. All I want to update are the Children of the main `<ul>` "Names" and "Jobs"

```
<ul>
   <li>Names
        <ul>
            <li>Mike</li>
            <li>Bob</li>
            <li>Steve</li>
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li>Jobs
        <ul>
            <li>Police</li>
            <li>Fire Fighter</li>
            <li>banker</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want the ability to only style the child `<li>`'s of my main `<ul>` not any of the sub items. The trick is I can not add any classes or id's to the list or sublist. I can put the whole thing in a containing div.

*NOTE if i add a class or ID to my  it will add it to all of them. This is a premade template i have no control over.

I was thinking I could do this:

```
<div id="mylist_container">
    <ul>
       <li>Names
            <ul>
                <li>Mike</li>
                <li>Bob</li>
                <li>Steve</li>
            </ul>
       </li>

       <li>Jobs
            <ul>
                <li>Police</li>
                <li>Fire Fighter</li>
                <li>banker</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And style it like this:

```
#mylist_container ul>l1{
    font:bold 18px arial;
}
```

Comment: Don't just think - try it!

Comment: I did try the above code but it made all the copy in the list and sub list bold 18px arial.

Comment: add a `>` between the `#mylist_container ul`.

Comment: Oh so you want the inner lists to not be affected. That makes sense. Do you have access to the original font styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you answered your own question!  Or at least 99% of the way.  Create one more child selector by adding `>` between `#mylist_container` and `ul`.  This will only target a `ul` that is a child of `#mylist_container` and not go any deeper in the structure.

```css
#mylist_container > ul > li { /* your styles */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#mylist_container > ul > li {
    font: bold 18px arial;
}
#mylist_container > ul > li ul{
    font: normal 10px arial; //assign the default view here
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SXrU6/)

Comment: That would only style Names and not Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my code example.
The first targets all `<li>` and the second targets only `<li>` inside of another `<li>`.

```
ul>li{
  any styles in here form the top level li
}

ul>li>ul>li{
  styles to cancel out the first styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
div ul li ul li{
    color:#000000;
}

div ul li{
    color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mk3g4/